# Error con FullCalendar PHP

Tags: php, fullcalendar

Hola estoy teniendo problema con la carga del FullCalendar.
He puesto todo el código pero me aparece el siguiente error en la línea 221

```
Uncaught TypeError: $(...).fullCalendar is not a function
```

Les copio el código completo para que me puedan ayudar.
Gracias

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <!-- Basic Page Needs
    ================================================== -->
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <!--[if IE]><meta http-equiv="x-ua-compatible" content="IE=9" /><![endif]-->
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <title>Calendario SUM | CYME Administradora</title>
    <meta name="description" content="">
    <meta name="keywords" content="administradora, consorcios, propiedad horizontal, edificios, unidades funcionales, departamento, negocios inmobiliarios, venta, alquiler, emprendimientos, construccion">
    <meta name="author" content="CYME">
    
    <!-- Favicons
    ================================================== -->
    <link rel="shortcut icon" href="img/favicon-47.png">
    <link rel="apple-touch-icon" href="img/favicon-47.png">
    <link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="72x72" href="img/apple-touch-icon-72x72.png">
    <link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="114x114" href="img/apple-touch-icon-114x114.png">

    <!-- Bootstrap -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"  href="css/bootstrap.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="fonts/font-awesome/css/font-awesome.css">

      <!-- Slider
    ================================================== -->
    <link href="css/owl.carousel.css" rel="stylesheet" media="screen">
    <link href="css/owl.theme.css" rel="stylesheet" media="screen">

    <!-- Stylesheet
    ================================================== -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"  href="css/style.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/responsive.css">

    <link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lato:100,300,400,700,900,100italic,300italic,400italic,700italic,900italic' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
    <link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:300italic,400italic,600italic,700italic,800italic,700,300,600,800,400' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
      
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false"></script>
<script>
        jssor_slider1_starter = function (containerId) {
            var options = {
                $AutoPlay: true,
                $DragOrientation: 1
            };
            var jssor_slider1 = new $JssorSlider$(containerId, options);
        };
      </script>
      
      <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jssor.js"></script>
      <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jssor.slider.js"></script>
      <script src="http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false" type="text/javascript"></script>
      
      <script type='text/javascript' src='js/jquery.min.js'></script>
      <script type='text/javascript' src='js/moment.min.js'></script>
      <!--Full Calendar-->
      <script src="js/fullcalendar.min.js"></script>
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/fullcalendar.min.css">
      
      
     <!-- Global site tag (gtag.js) - Google Analytics -->
<script async src="https://www.googletagmanager.com/gtag/js?id=UA-115945504-1"></script>
<script>
  window.dataLayer = window.dataLayer || [];
  function gtag(){dataLayer.push(arguments);}
  gtag('js', new Date());

  gtag('config', 'UA-115945504-1');
</script>
    <!-- HTML5 shim and Respond.js for IE8 support of HTML5 elements and media queries -->
    <!-- WARNING: Respond.js doesn't work if you view the page via file:// -->
    <!--[if lt IE 9]>
      <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/html5shiv/3.7.2/html5shiv.min.js"></script>
      <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/respond/1.4.2/respond.min.js"></script>
    <![endif]-->
  </head>
  <body>
    <!-- Navigation
    ==========================================-->
    <nav id="tf-menu" class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top">
      <div class="container">
        <!-- Brand and toggle get grouped for better mobile display -->
        <div class="navbar-header">
          <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
            <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
          </button>
            <a href="index.html"><img src="img/nav-bar.png"></a>
        </div>

        <!-- Collect the nav links, forms, and other content for toggling -->
        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
          <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
            <li><a href="index.html#tf-home" class="page-scroll">Home</a></li>
            <li><a href="index.html#tf-about" class="page-scroll">¿Qué hacemos?</a></li>
            <li><a href="index.html#tf-team" class="page-scroll">Administradora</a></li>
            <li><a href="index.html#tf-works" class="page-scroll">Negocios Inmobiliarios</a></li>
            <li><a href="index.html#tf-clients" class="page-scroll">Emprendimientos</a></li>
            <li><a href="index.html#tf-contact" class="page-scroll">Contacto</a></li>
          </ul>
        </div><!-- /.navbar-collapse -->
      </div><!-- /.container-fluid -->
    </nav>

    <!-- Home Page
    ==========================================-->
      <div id="tf-edificio" class="text-center">
        <div class="overlay">
        </div>
    </div>
      <div id="tf-about">
        <div class="container">
                <div class="col-md-8 col-md-offset-2">
                    <div class="about-text">
                        <p class="intro" align="justify"><strong>Señores propietarios del edificio</strong>
                            <br>
                            <br>A continuación les dejamos un formulario para que ustedes puedan reservar el SUM (Salón de Usos Múltiples) si desean usarlo y teniendo en cuenta las fechas que no están disponibles.
                            <br>
                            <br>
                        </p>
                    </div>
                    <form action="calendario.php" method="post" id="form" class="contact-form">
                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="col-md-6">
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <label for="nombre">Nombre y Apellido</label>
                                    <input type="name" class="form-control" required name="name" placeholder="Nombre y Apellido">
                                </div>
                            </div>                        
                        </div>
                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="col-md-6">
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <label for="nombre">Dirección</label>
                                    <select name="edificio" class="form-control" input type="name" class="form-control">
                                            <option>Dirección del edificio</option>
                                    </select>
                                </div>
                            </div>  
                        <div class="col-md-3">
                            <div class="form-group">
                                    <label for="piso">Piso</label>
                                    <input type="name" class="form-control" required name="piso" placeholder="Piso">
                                </div>
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <label for="depto">Departamento</label>
                                    <input type="name" class="form-control" required name="depto" placeholder="Departamento">
                                </div>
                        </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-md-6">
                            <div class="form-group">
                                    <label for="celular">Teléfono Celular</label>
                                    <input type="tel" class="form-control" required name="celular" placeholder="Teléfono Celular">
                                </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-md-6">
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <label for="email">Email</label>
                                    <input type="email" class="form-control" required name="email" placeholder="ejemplo@cyme.com.ar">
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-md-3">
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <label for="rango">Seleccione la fecha que desea reservar</label>
                                    <br><input type="date" name="fecha_seleccionada" class="form-control" required name="fecha_seleccionada">
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    <br>
                        <button type="submit" class="btn tf-btn btn-default">Enviar</button>
                    </form>
                 </div>
            </div>
            <div class="container">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-md-8">
                            <div id="calendarioSUM"></div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
          <br>
          <br>
        </div>
    
    <nav id="footer">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="pull-left fnav">
                <p>© CYME | Administradora - Negocios Inmobiliarios - Emprendimientos | Diseñado por <a href="http://www.behance.net/msevero" target="_blank">Matías Severo</a></p>
            </div>
            <div class="pull-right fnav">
                <ul class="footer-social">
                    <li><a href="mailto:matias.severo@gmail.com" target="_blank"><i class="fa fa-at"></i></a></li>
                    <li><a href="http://www.behance.net/msevero" target="_blank"><i class="fa fa-behance-square"></i></a></li>
                    <li><a href="http://www.twitter.com/msportfolio" target="_blank"><i class="fa fa-twitter"></i></a></li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
    </nav>


    <!-- jQuery (necessary for Bootstrap's JavaScript plugins) -->
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.1.11.1.js"></script>
    <!-- Include all compiled plugins (below), or include individual files as needed -->
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/bootstrap.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/SmoothScroll.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.isotope.js"></script>

    <script src="js/owl.carousel.js"></script>

    <!-- Javascripts
    ================================================== -->
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/main.js"></script>
    <script>
        $(document).ready(function(){
            $('#calendarioSUM').fullCalendar();
        });
      </script>
      
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: JQuery se está cargando muy tarde y necesitas hacer un defer a lo que estás intentando ejecutar para que se ejecute después de tener JQuery.

Comment: Qué vendría a ser un DEFER? Y si se carga muy tarde JQuery, debería ponerlo en una línea más arriba del código?

Comment: jQuery NO se está cargando tarde, porque de lo contrario no ejecutaría la función que llama al fullCalendar `$('#calendarioSUM').fullCalendar();`

Comment: revisa que se cargue el archivo fullcalendar.min.js en los sources del inspector de elementos del navegador y que la manera de llamar a su constructor sea con fullCalendar

Comment: @MatiasSevero es por la forma en que acomodas los scripts, deberia primero ser **Jquery (Veo que tienes dos Jquery, elige uno), Luego Bootstrap**, después los demás, que vendrían siendo **fullCalendar**, etc.

Comment: El código `<script> $(document).ready(function(){ $('#calendarioSUM').fullCalendar();}); </script>` debes de agregarlo en el encabezado de su página, como lo indica
en la documentación [Documentación](https://fullcalendar.io/docs/initialization), y tomar en cuenta lo que menciona @Cig **La sobrecarga de archivos JQUERY**.